# How to resize display of FramePanel in GXT?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

```
public class View implements IsWidget, EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RootPanel.get().add(asWidget());
    }

    @Override
    public Widget asWidget() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
        FramedPanel cp = new FramedPanel();
        vp.setBorderWidth(1);
        vp.setWidth("100%");
        vp.setHeight("100%");
        cp.setWidth("100%");
        cp.setHeight("100%");
        vp.add(cp);

        return vp;
    }
```

I want fill that Frame Panel  in VerticalPanel.
So I was designate the height and width of the VerticalPanel and FramedPanel as 100%.
however, Results were different from expected results.

How to resize display of FramePanel in GXT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you need to take care:

1) If you want Framed panel to take 100% of verticalPanel, why to use VerticalPanel then.

2) Do not use GWT widgets with GXT widgets.  GXT provides several widgets that can easily help you in layouting your UI. [Here](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/guides/ui/layout/LayoutContainers.html) is the link to GXT layout containers

3) If, you wanyt to use VerticalPanel, used VerticalLayoutContainer.

```
VerticalLayoutContainer vlc = new VerticalLayoutContainer();
vlc.add(cp,new VerticalLayoutData(1,1));
```

It gives 100% of available width and height. See [here](https://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.x/guides/ui/layout/containers/VerticalLayoutContainer.html#ui-_-layout/containers/VerticalLayoutContainer_-_vertical_layout_data). In the section getHeight or getWidth.

Use **setResize(true);** if you want your framed panel to resize itself

Comment: *DO* use GWT widgets and GXT widgets, at least after GXT 3. That said, VerticalPanel sizes itself to its children, whereas VerticalLayoutContainer sizes its children to fit it. I'd add http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/concepts/Layouts.html as another link to review.

Comment: @Colin Alworth: I remember u saying me to use GXT widgets when i was using GXT 3.0.1. May be its changed after 3.1

Comment: In GXT 2 that would almost certainly be true. In GXT 3 (both 3.0 and 3.1) you *can* mix and match, but just be aware that GWT widgets may not do what you actually mean - in this case, VerticalPanel is not doing what the user wanted, so switching to the GXT class is better. But if they actually wanted the VerticalPanel behavior (of sizing to fit its children, rather than resizing the children to fit the space), then there is no reason not to use VerticalPanel.

Comment: If you want to do anything with layouts, GWT's own Layout Panel classes could work (though there aren't many, and they aren't very powerful), otherwise just use GXT's Layout Containers. In that regard, your advice is 100% correct.

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I solved problem through the answer to you.